# How to show log file data in html table using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, laravel

I want to display my logfile data in html tablualar form using php. My log file data looks like

> 2019-08-01 07:45:13   112.196.23.170  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0    42112452     and user clicked on this email: mike@jvpsus.com    India   IN  Punjab

I want to display **2019-08-01 07:45:13** in table row

then **112.196.23.170** in second second row

Then show whole **Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:68.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/68.0**

then id **42112452** 4th row

then sixth row **and user clicked on this email: mike@jvpsus.com**

Last seventh row **India IN Punjab**

Whenever i am trying to fetch the data in array, after foreach array break into key and value. I am trying to explode (' ', $string) with space. But whole sentance character with space getting into seprate array index.

**When i am trying to foreach it's giving me this output**
[image]

**What exectly i want output is below**

[image]

Here is my code

````
$logFile = 'testlog.log';
$lines = file($logFile); // Get each line of the file and store it as an array

// echo "<pre>";
// print_r($lines);

foreach($lines as $line)
{
    // list($date, $time, $ip, $domain,$no,$mail,$cnt, $cod, $state) = explode(' ', $line);
    $output = preg_replace('!\s+!', ' ', $line);
     echo "<pre>";
    print_r (explode(" ",$output));



}


?>```
````

Comment: Are the first and second items the same length in every row?

Comment: If possible, change the logfile format. It's hard to parse as you noticed

Comment: @BrettGregson Nope

Comment: The first column will be a date, so that should be the same. The next is an IP address? Are any of those values ever null or empty? And will the second last string always follow the format "and user clicked on this email..."?

Comment: Solved, separated the log file data with special symbol and explode the value on the basis of symbol

Answer (score 1):

Something to remind you: Try to logging in csv format may make it easier to parse the log lines. but if it's not possible, then:

- Change your regular expression. and move it outside the `foreach` loop.
- If you want to make it a table, use `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` tags.
- It will be better if you change this to an AJAX API:

  - return the split data by JSON.
  - and render it at front end.

Try to complete the following code.

```
$logFile = 'testlog.log';
$lines = file($logFile); // Get each line of the file and store it as an array

// The regular expression to break lines
$rgx = '/(\d+-\d+-\d+) (\d+:\d+:\d+) (\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+) (.*? \(.*\)) (.*? .*?) (\d*) (.* email: .*@.*?) (.*$)/';

echo "<table>\n";
foreach($lines as $line) {
    echo "<tr>\n";
    $output = preg_split($rgx, $line);
    ...
    echo "<td>$output[0]</td>\n"
    ...
    echo "</tr>\n";
}
echo "</table>\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

a tab symbol as a special symbol might work